# php-ldap PHP 7.2 - Centos 7

Tags: centos7, openldap, php-7.2

I try to install PHP 7.2 LDAP in Centos 7 with

```
yum install php-ldap
```

i also has uncomment extension=ldap.so in php.ini
but ldap still has no longer in phpInfo.
Anyone help? i use apache.